# pentaho report designer : how to modify reporting output?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

By default, there are many output formats such as html stream, html paginated, excel, pdf etc. I just want to keep html stream and pdf as output formats. Can anyone tell me how to change it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options while you create and save a RD report:

1. Use a default output and allow end user to select other output format on runtime.
2. Use a default output and do not allow user to select any other format.

You would be able to view these options when you try to publish your report on the repository, you can export it and then publish the report on BA server but i would recommend you connect to BA server repository and then publish the report.
While you are publishing on bottom left you would be able to view ***Output type*** and if you want to lock that output type of not.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I know the option 2, however with this, I can only choose one output format. I want to keep 2 formats. Is there any way?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, could you please try using attribute on the right side called output-format ( use html, pdf, xls, rtf, csv, xml as values) and then use lock-output-format to lock those output formats.

Comment: Unfortunetly, on this option, I can choose only one format too. So I guess there's no solution?

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/189932-How-to-remove-excel-format-from-the-output-report-designer/

Here, everything is explained!